# For what values of $r$ are the vectors $(r, 1), (r + 2, r)$ linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a = b = 0$.

Then 
$ar + br + 2b = 0$ and $a + br = 0$ imply any $r \in \mathbb R$ is suitable.

Is that in/correct?

Comment: You can't start by assuming $a=b=0$ or your statement is vacuous.

Comment: @ Bye_World, how can I apply the definition of linear independence to this problem?

Comment: To clarify the definition, as your solution suggests some confusion to me: A set of vectors $\{v_1,...v_n\}$ is linearly independent iff for scalars $a_1,...a_n$, $a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n = 0 \implies a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$. You've checked the reverse direction, which is $a_1 = ... = a_n = 0 \implies  a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n = 0$ which is true for an arbitrary set of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $x$ and $y$ real numbers, such that
$$x(r,1)+y(r+2,r)=0$$ (1)
this gives $$rx+(r+2)y=0$$ (2)
and
$$x+yr=0$$ from (2) we get $$r(-yr)+(r+2)y=0$$ or $$y(-r^2+r+2)=0$$ the rest is case work

Answer (score 3):

$ (r,1), (r+2,r)$ are linearly dependent $ \iff \det \begin{pmatrix} r & r+2 \\ 1 & r \end{pmatrix} = 0.  $

$$ 0 = \det \begin{pmatrix} r & r+2 \\ 1 & r \end{pmatrix} = r^2 - r - 2 = (r-2)(r+1) \implies r \in \{-1,2 \}. $$

Therefore the two vectors are linearly independent iff $ r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1,2\}. $

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by assuming that the vectors are linearly dependent for some real number $r$. Now there exists a real number $a$ such that $(ar,a) = (r+2,r)$, hence we must have $a = r$.

This implies that $ar = r^2 = r+2$ so we can solve for $r$. By using the quadratic formula, we get $r = -1$ or $r = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors are linearly dependent if one is a multiple of the other.  In this case, $$(r,1)=a(r+2,r)=(ar+2a,ra)$$
Hence we get the equations $r=ar+2a, 1=ra$.  Plugging the second equation into the first (using $a=1/r$), we get $$r=1+\frac{2}{r}$$
We multiply both sides by $r$, which gives the quadratic $r^2=r+2$, which has two roots: $r=-1, r=2$.  This corresponds to $a=-1$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$, respectively.

Comment: and if $r=0$? what is in this case?

Comment: $r=0$ is not possible for $ar=1$, so that cannot give us a solution.  In any case you can check $r=0$ by hand -- $(0,1), (2,0)$ are not dependent.